# Using Scanner in Java to parse a text file or console input and ran into errors

Tags: java, java.util.scanner, java-6

I am trying to read in values from a file separated by white space between the individual items and carriage returns.

So the text file is something like

```
1 lunch box 3.99
2 jelly donuts 1.99
4 cases of beer 36.99
2 chess boards 24.99
```

With these values I am trying to construct objects... So the object will be made up of the quantity, the first thing on the line, a name - the second thing on the line, and a price the last thing on the line. So the constructor is like:

```
product(int x, String name, float price) { 
 this.x = x;
 this.name = name;
 this.price = price;
}
```

My problem is the way I have coded the scanner is running into trouble when trying to parse everything. So I receive a java.util.InputMismatchException. If I use an algorithm like:

```
if (scannerRef.hasNextInt()) 
  arraylistRef.intThing = scannerRef.nextInt();

if (scannerRef.hasNext())
   arraylistRef.name = scannerRef.next();

if (scannerRef.hasNextFloat())
   arrayListRef.price = scannerRef.nextFloat();
```

then the code the way I have it puts each individual primitive or String in its own object instead of looping through an entire line then adding it to an object

I hope this makes sense. Thanks for reading if you are reading this now.

the main part of my code I am concerned about is this: 
the way I have it here with the above type of algorithms commented out puts everything in to the same object but runs into the java.util.InputMismatchException dingo brains

```
// loop while there is text to read
while (s1.hasNextLine()) {
    Product p = new Product(p.quantity = s1.next);
  //if (s1.hasNextInt())
     p.quantity = s1.nextInt();


//  else 
     p.name = s1.next(); // to get strings

     // else if(s1.hasNextFloat())
     p.price = s1.nextFloat();

 // now add the line to the product arraylist
 foo.add(p);

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to take the file data line by line into a String (whatever Collection type you prefer) and then split it wherever you find white space and store the data accordingly. To take in the whole line you'd use:

```
nextLine();
```

That way you'd get a String say `"1 lunch box 3.99"`. You would then split this wherever you find white space and store `1` as an int, `lunch` and `box` as Strings, and `3.99` as a double (using doubles for monies is not recommended).

You can search for useful methods here: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html  For example, the split() method.

Here's an example on how to use split():

Let's say your input line is `1 lunch box 3.99`. You have already read it into a String as follows:

```
String example = "1 lunch box 3.99"
```

To split this String at white space using the split() method, you'd do the following:

```
String[] splitString = example.split(" ");
```

This will give you an array of String with the following values:

```
{"1", "lunch", "box", "3.99"};
```

Then you can parse these values into their proper type using things like `Integer.parseInt`, `Double.parseDouble`, etc.

Comment: Nick is correct, however, I would actually recommend using a double for money.  Float is not as precise as a double, which could eventually cause issues with something like balance.

Comment: Thank-you @nickecarlo . Yes, this may work. I had not thought about this. What about the fact that 'lunch box' has a space between it though? Will this not make parsing products with multiple words more difficult?

Comment: @user2085446 It would. You could change the file to be a CSV if you're worried about that and then split at the comma. This is a very simple way to get you going but I'm sure there's ways you can make it work. I can think of crude ways off the top of my head (like concatening the Strings with a space in the middle) but that would make all of this way too cluttered.

Comment: @DavidChristo true but doubles still have precision issues, albeit on a much smaller scale than floats. I would suggest using ints with the % operator and do calculations on cents instead of dollars (or whatever currency one's dealing with).

Comment: thanks @nickecarlo and others - does anyone know of a tutorial that shows how to parse the resulting string using white space as a delimeter though? commas is too easy. :D

Comment: @user2085446 for the split method you'd do `split(" ")` to split at white space. Not sure if that's what you're asking for though.

Comment: Thanks @nickecarlo :) I can experiment some with this. Thanks again everyone.

Comment: @user2085446 No problem. I will update the answer in a couple of minutes with an example.

Comment: @user2085446 Updated my answer. Hope that helps.

Comment: cool. @nickecarlo thanks for updating that. I have a better understanding now.